# Laravel 5.4: select the records that's within 2 days only

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

I am need to pull all the records that's within 2 days only for example
today is 24/7 so I need all the records in 23/7 and 22/7

I try this

```
->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)')
```

but not working it gets the records from two days ago
also try this

```
->whereDate( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays( 2 ) )
```

but it includes the records from today also which I don't want.

How should I do this using `carbon` or `DATE`

Comment: If today is 24/7, You want to get 23/7 and 22/7 except 24/7 right?

Comment: @Ts8060 yes that what I need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do:

```
->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::today()->subDays( 2 ))
->whereDate('created_at', '!=', Carbon::today());
```

This will exclude today.

If you prefer a bit more raw queries then you can do:

```
->whereBetween(\DB::raw("DATE(`created_at`)"), [ Carbon::today()->subDays(2), Carbon::today()->subDays(1) ]);
```

Note: Using today because it makes the code look more expressive but `now` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Do like following:

```
->whereDate( 'created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays( 2 ) )
->whereDate( 'created_at', '<', Carbon::today() )
```

Comment: that included today records!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereBetween` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDays(2)->startOfDay(), now()->endOfDay()])
```

--

You can also use multiple `where` clauses:

```
->where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(2)->startOfDay())
->where('created_at', '<', now()->endOfDay())
```

--

You can also use `whereDate`

```
->whereDate('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(2)->startOfDay())
->whereDate('created_at', '<', now()->endOfDay())
```

--

Carbon docs:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: this gives an error `Call to undefined function Acme\Repositories\Supplier\now()`

Comment: I think this is the best solution but I think it should be `now()->startOfDay()->subDays(2), now()->startOfDay()`. To get OPs desired result.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? you can replace the instances of `now()` and add `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of your class and do `Carbon::now()` instead

Comment: @Josh `Carbon::now()->startOfDay()` is also known as `Carbon::today()`

Answer (score 1):

Add this, might work for you

```
->whereDate( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::today()->subDays( 2 ) )
->whereDate( 'created_at', '!=', Carbon::today())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
   ->whereDate( 'created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays( 2 ) )